# Selenium IDE Recording Scripts converts into Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After Recording scripts from Selenium IDE and converting code in `Java/Junit 4/WebDriver` when I copy paste code in `Eclipse`, this error is raised:

> Syntax Error on token "111", Identifier Expected

[image]

Comment: Change the class name. As "111" is not valid class name.

Answer (score 0):

A java class name can not start with a number, it must begin with a "Java Letter" which does not include numbers. Here's a link to common conventions:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: can you post the whole class?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the class name as a class name cannot start with a number. By java conventions the initial letter of the each word in your class name must be UPPERCASE and further letters can be lowercase.